# Can a derived event be used as an initiator for a temporal context?

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing

I am trying to have a derived event trigger an AbsenceEPA, by having the associated temporal context be initiated by the said derived event. Is that possible? This is the configuration I have:

```
    {
    "epn":{
        "events":[
            {
                "name":"PollingCount",
                "createdDate":"Fri Feb 19 2016",
                "attributes":[
                    {
                        "name":"restaurantId",
                        "type":"String",
                        "dimension":"0"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"pollCount",
                        "type":"Integer",
                        "dimension":0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name":"PrinterContextUpdate",
                "createdDate":"Fri Feb 19 2016",
                "attributes":[
                    {
                        "name":"restaurantId",
                        "type":"String",
                        "dimension":0
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"lastTimestamp",
                        "type":"String",
                        "dimension":0
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"entityId",
                        "type":"String",
                        "dimension":"0"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"entityType",
                        "type":"String",
                        "dimension":0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name":"PrinterStoppedPolling",
                "createdDate":"Tue Feb 23 2016",
                "attributes":[
                    {
                        "name":"restaurantId",
                        "type":"String",
                        "dimension":"0"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"lastTimestamp",
                        "type":"String",
                        "dimension":0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "epas":[
            {
                "name":"CountEPA",
                "epaType":"Aggregate",
                "context":"CountCompositeContext",
                "inputEvents":[
                    {
                        "name":"PrinterContextUpdate",
                        "alias":"pp",
                        "consumptionPolicy":"Consume",
                        "instanceSelectionPolicy":"First"
                    }
                ],
                "computedVariables":[
                    {
                        "name":"Count",
                        "aggregationType":"Count",
                        "pp":"1"
                    }
                ],
                "evaluationPolicy":"Deferred",
                "cardinalityPolicy":"Single",
                "internalSegmentation":[],
                "derivedEvents":[
                    {
                        "name":"PollingCount",
                        "reportParticipants":false,
                        "expressions":{
                            "restaurantId":"ArrayGet(pp.restaurantId, ArraySize(pp.restaurantId) - 1)",
                            "pollCount":"Count"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name":"PrinterStoppedPollingEPA",
                "createdDate":"Tue Feb 23 2016",
                "epaType":"Absence",
                "context":"SentLastPoll",
                "inputEvents":[
                    {
                        "name":"PollingCount",
                        "alias":"pc",
                        "consumptionPolicy":"Consume",
                        "instanceSelectionPolicy":"First"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"PrinterContextUpdate",
                        "alias":"pu",
                        "consumptionPolicy":"Consume",
                        "instanceSelectionPolicy":"First"
                    }
                ],
                "computedVariables":[],
                "evaluationPolicy":"Deferred",
                "cardinalityPolicy":"Single",
                "internalSegmentation":[],
                "derivedEvents":[
                    {
                        "name":"PrinterStoppedPolling",
                        "reportParticipants":false,
                        "expressions":{
                            "restaurantId":"pc.restaurantId",
                            "lastTimestamp":"pu.lastTimestamp"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "contexts":{
            "temporal":[
                {
                    "name":"CountTemporalContext",
                    "type":"TemporalInterval",
                    "atStartup":false,
                    "neverEnding":false,
                    "initiators":[
                        {
                            "initiatorType":"Event",
                            "initiatorPolicy":"Ignore",
                            "name":"PrinterContextUpdate"
                        }
                    ],
                    "terminators":[
                        {
                            "terminatorType":"RelativeTime",
                            "terminationType":"Terminate",
                            "relativeTime":"90000"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name":"SentLastPoll",
                    "createdDate":"Tue Feb 23 2016",
                    "type":"TemporalInterval",
                    "atStartup":false,
                    "neverEnding":false,
                    "initiators":[
                        {
                            "initiatorType":"Event",
                            "initiatorPolicy":"Add",
                            "name":"PollingCount"
                        }
                    ],
                    "terminators":[
                        {
                            "terminatorType":"Event",
                            "terminatorPolicy":"First",
                            "terminationType":"Terminate",
                            "name":"PrinterContextUpdate"
                        },
                        {
                            "terminatorType":"RelativeTime",
                            "terminationType":"Terminate",
                            "relativeTime":"60000"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "segmentation":[
                {
                    "name":"CountSegmentationContext",
                    "participantEvents":[
                        {
                            "name":"PrinterContextUpdate",
                            "expression":"PrinterContextUpdate.restaurantId"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "composite":[
                {
                    "name":"CountCompositeContext",
                    "temporalContexts":[
                        {
                            "name":"CountTemporalContext"
                        }
                    ],
                    "segmentationContexts":[
                        {
                            "name":"CountSegmentationContext"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "consumers":[
            {
                "name":"alert",
                "createdDate":"Fri Feb 19 2016",
                "type":"Rest",
                "properties":[
                    {
                        "name":"URL",
                        "value":"http://api-dev.priorhq.com/polling_monitor"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"contentType",
                        "value":"application/json"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"formatter",
                        "value":"json"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"delimiter",
                        "value":";"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"tagDataSeparator",
                        "value":"="
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"dateFormat",
                        "value":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                    }
                ],
                "events":[
                    {
                        "name":"PollingCount"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"PrinterStoppedPolling"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "producers":[],
        "name":"Prior"
    }
}
```

The derived event is PollingCount and the temporal context is PrinterStoppedPolling.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is entirely possible. 
However I think you have an error in your Absence EPA. The PollingCount event would serve as initiator to this EPAs context. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but there is a contradiction in your logic - in absence pattern when you specify input events you mean for this EPA to report when those events are absent. 
I think perhaps you meant just the PrinterContextUpdate event to be input to the absence EPA? In case such event does not arrive from the moment PollingCount was derived and till the expiration of the temporal context, then Absence EPA will report